# Pyinputplus Passing to a Function

Tags: python, list, dictionary, input

I am working on a script to easily determine the waterfowl limits of a state by typing its name. I am also using the pyinputplus module for input validation, but I am hung up on one important step.

```
# Function of the code is to input name of central flyway state (waterfowl hunting), and print the limit of ducks and geese for that state.
# Please see following link for more information: https://www.ducks.org/conservation/where-ducks-unlimited-works/waterfowl-migration-flyways/du-projects-central-flyway

# Imports pyinputplus for input validation
import pyinputplus as pyip


# Dictionary of Central Flyway States and their respective limits
Montana = {
    "State:": "Montana",
    "Duck Limit:": "7",
    "Goose Limit:": "6",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Oct. 2 - Jan. 14",
}
Wyoming = {
    "State:": "Wyoming",
    "Duck Limit:": "7",
    "Goose Limit:": "3",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Sept. 26 - Jan. 8",
}
Colorado = {
    "State:": "Colorado",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "3",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Oct. 11 - Dec. 1 and Dec. 13 - Jan. 25",
}
NM = {
    "State:": "New Mexico",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "5",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Oct. 4 - Jan. 2",
}
Texas = {
    "State:": "Texas",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "5",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Nov. 13 - Nov. 28 and Dec. 4 - Jan. 30",
}
Oklahoma = {
    "State:": "Oklahoma",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "8",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Oct. 17 - Jan. 13",
}
Kansas = {
    "State:": "Kansas",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "6",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Nov 1. - Jan. 4 and Jan. 17 - Jan. 25",
}
Nebraska = {
    "State:": "Nebraska",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "5",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Oct. 3 - Dec. 15 and Jan. 6 - Jan. 27",
}
SD = {
    "State:": "South Dakota",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "3",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Oct. 11 - Jan. 15",
}
ND = {
    "State:": "North Dakota",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "8",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Sept. 27 - Dec. 7",
}

# Asking user to type name of state
print(
    """Please type Name of Central Flyway State for waterfowl information.
"""
)

# pyip module with a whitelist of available state names. Will return error if input is not whitelisted.
result = pyip.inputMenu(
    [
        "Montana",
        "Wyoming",
        "Colorado",
        "New Mexico",
        "Texas",
        "Oklahoma",
        "Kansas",
        "Nebraska",
        "South Dakota",
        "North Dakota",
    ],
)
# Function to return the result of inputMenu and call out the corresponding dictionary with it's key:value pairs
def statefunction(result):
    print(result)

    if statefunction(result) == "Montana":
        print(Montana.items)
    elif statefunction(result) == "Wyoming":
        print(Wyoming.items)
    elif statefunction(result) == "Colorado":
        print(Colorado.items)
    elif statefunction(result) == "New Mexico":
        print(NM.items)
    elif statefunction(result) == "Texas":
        print(Texas.items)
    elif statefunction(result) == "Oklahoma":
        print(Oklahoma.items)
    elif statefunction(result) == "Kansas":
        print(Kansas.items)
    elif statefunction(result) == "Nebraska":
        print(Nebraska.items)
    elif statefunction(result) == "South Dakota":
        print(SD.items)
    elif statefunction(result) == "North Dakota":
        print(ND.items)
```

I would like for the code to iterate through the 'if' and 'elif' statements and print the items for the corresponding dictionaries. For example, if I type "Texas", into the inputMenu when prompted, I want the dictionary key:value pairs for Texas to print to the screen. Right now, all that happens is I type in "Texas", or any other whitelisted string under the inputMenu, and the code finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You have done everything correctly, but just need to parse the `state` as an `argument` into the function and also call the function.

```py
def statefunction(state):
    print(state)

statefunction(state)
```

This will work.

Comment: I didn't realize I was forgetting that small of a detail. Also, when I use the suggested format, I am unable to make the statefunction(state) display the input that was typed in the inputMenu. For example, if I leave statefunction(state), it will cause an error because state is not defined, so if I change (state) to a state from my dictionary such as Wyoming, it will look like statefunction(Wyoming), and display the key:value pairs from that dictionary, regardless of what state I type in the inputMenu. Do you have any ideas to help with this? Thanks!

Comment: i was just answering the question at hand, but there are (at least) two other things that you could do. [1] use `if` or the `switch` statement to select the `dict` to parse in or alternatively [2] create a `dict` of `dicts` (nested dicts). Both of those would satisfy the problem also.

Comment: Before I dive deep into your other answer, I want to try to get this one working first. I am brand new to python and am learning immense amounts from reading your code. Anyway, I attempted to use an if statement to iterate through the 'dictionaries', but I am unable to achieve the desired result. I have modified my original question to show what I have now. For whatever reason, I cannot perfect the 'if' and 'elif' statements so they recognize that I am calling out to a 'dict'. I would like for it to be like I described in the last comment. Can you help with this? Thank you!

Comment: it would be as simple as `if result == "Montana": state = Montana` and so on for each state. You would then finally parse `state` into the `statefunction`... i actually showed the second answer below because it avoids a series of `if` statements. I am glad that it helps... please upvote answers that are constructive.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a second answer here. Here we use the `sys` module and the `getattr` function to convert `strings` from the input to `dicts` that you defined in the code.

```py
import sys

# Dictionary of Central Flyway States and their respective limits
Montana = {
    "State:": "Montana",
    "Duck Limit:": "7",
    "Goose Limit:": "6",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Oct. 2 - Jan. 14",
}
Wyoming = {
    "State:": "Wyoming",
    "Duck Limit:": "7",
    "Goose Limit:": "3",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Sept. 26 - Jan. 8",
}
Colorado = {
    "State:": "Colorado",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "3",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Oct. 11 - Dec. 1 and Dec. 13 - Jan. 25",
}
NM = {
    "State:": "New Mexico",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "5",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Oct. 4 - Jan. 2",
}
Texas = {
    "State:": "Texas",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "5",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Nov. 13 - Nov. 28 and Dec. 4 - Jan. 30",
}
Oklahoma = {
    "State:": "Oklahoma",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "8",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Oct. 17 - Jan. 13",
}
Kansas = {
    "State:": "Kansas",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "6",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Nov 1. - Jan. 4 and Jan. 17 - Jan. 25",
}
Nebraska = {
    "State:": "Nebraska",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "5",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Oct. 3 - Dec. 15 and Jan. 6 - Jan. 27",
}
SD = {
    "State:": "South Dakota",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "3",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Oct. 11 - Jan. 15",
}
ND = {
    "State:": "North Dakota",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "8",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Sept. 27 - Dec. 7",
}

# Asking user to type name of state
print(
    """Please type Name of Central Flyway State for waterfowl information.
"""
)


def str_to_dict(my_string):
    ''' convert string to dict '''
    return getattr(sys.modules[__name__], my_string)

state = input('add your state: ')

state_dict = str_to_dict(state)



def statefunction(s):
    print(s)


statefunction(state_dict)
```

You could do checking in the state input string too...

The output is this:

```
add your state: Montana   
{'State:': 'Montana', 'Duck Limit:': '7', 'Goose Limit:': '6', 'Waterfowl Season:': 'Oct. 2 - Jan. 
14'}
```